# How to get @Autowire annotation work with Hessian web service? (Setter autowire work fine)

Tags: java, spring, hessian

I have spring project use Hessian web service (userMgr). In my client (UserProfileHelperImpl), spring config work with setter autowiring but not with @Autowire annotation. How can I get the same thing with @Autowire? Thanks.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/jsp" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>web</display-name>
    <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
      <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xmlns:dwr="http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
  http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd"    
default-autowire="byName">
    <context:annotation-config /> 
    <context:spring-configured />
    <task:annotation-driven />
    <import resource="applicationContext-service.xml" />
    <import resource="applicationContext-business.xml" />
</beans>
```

applicationContext-service.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd"
  default-autowire="byName">  
  <bean id="userMgr"
class="org.springframework.remoting.caucho.HessianProxyFactoryBean" scope="prototype">
    <property name="hessian2Request" value="true" />
    <property name="hessian2Reply" value="true" />
    <property name="serviceUrl" value='#{config.getFullUrl("userMgr")}' />
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.core.business.UserMgr" />
  </bean>
</beans>
```

applicationContext-business.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd"
  default-autowire="byName">
  <bean id="userProfileHelper" class="com.web.business.common.UserProfileHelperImpl" scope="prototype">
<!--      <property name="userMgr" ref="userMgr"/> -->
  </bean>
</beans>
```

UserProfileHelper.java

```
package com.web.business.common;

@Component
public interface UserProfileHelper {
  Profile getUserProfile(String userName);
}
```

UserProfileHelperImpl.java

```
package com.web.business.common;

public class UserProfileHelperImpl implements UserProfileHelper {
  @Autowired // this does not work
  private UserMgr userMgr;

  // this work
  /*public void setUserMgr(UserMgr userMgr) {
    this.userMgr = userMgr;
  }*/
}
```

UserMgr.java

```
package com.core.business;

public interface UserMgr {

  Profile getUserProfile(String userName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be writing `AttributeMgr` in place of `UserMgr`?

```
@Autowired
private AttributeMgr userMgr;
```

Comment: Also, in `<property name="serviceInterface" value="com.business.UserMgr" />` shouldn't it be `com.core.business.UserMgr` in place of just `com.business.UserMgr`? I'm not sure how Setter is working for you.

Comment: I reviewed all again and corrected some place. Because each file is long and all are same, so I remove some redundant code.

Comment: You are giving `default-autowire="byName"` while `@Autowired` use `"byType"`. `"byName"` always inject a Dependency using setter. If you want to use the annotation then do not specify the `default-autowire="byName"` or maybe use `@Qualifier` in addition to `@Autowired`.

Comment: In `applicationContext-service.xml` and `applicationContext-business.xml`,  I removed `default-autowire="byName"`, and add explicit `autowire="byType"` to each bean definition. And I get this error: 
`org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.core.business.UserMgr] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`. I also try `@Qualifier("userMgr")` but not work, same error.

Comment: If I'm not wrong then you have tried `@Qualifier` with `default-autowire="byName"` right? If not then you should do it in addition to `default-autowire="byName"`. Also, there is no need to add explicit `autowire="byType"`. You can just remove `default-autowire="byName"` and it should work.

Comment: What I did is: remove setter, then combine some case (1: keep `@Autowire`, don't use `@Qualifier`, remove `default-autowire`; 2: keep `@Autowire` & `@Qualifier`, just remove `default-autowire`) but all isn't work (error as above). Additional information, I create object like this: `ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:applicationContext.xml"); userProfileHelper = (UserProfileHelper) context.getBean("userProfileHelper");`. I don't know why setter work but `@Autowire` :))

Comment: Have you tried this? Remove Setter, Keep `@Autowired`, Keep `@Qualifier("usrMgr")`, DO NOT Remove `default-autowire="byName"`?

Comment: I have just tried. But it's not work too (`NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`)

Comment: I think it should be another error, because there is that bean (`userMgr`) when using setter.